# Node.js response.write doesn't send data on consecutive request

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have a Node.js(Express) server. The server is listening for `POST` request with route `/enddev`. The server is configured to keep every connection alive for at least 55 seconds.

My client sends POST requests to `/enddev` route every 10 seconds. The communication uses the same connection on every request, since the timeout is restarted on every new request.

The problem is that the client receives data only upon the first request. Every consecutive request is registered by the server but `res.write` seems not working.

Here is some code:

```
app.post("/enddev", (req, res) => {
  console.log("REQUEST TO ", req.route.path);
  console.log("Req Header ", req.headers);
  console.log("Body:", req.body);
  res.write("Thanks!");
});
```

Few lines downward:

```
server.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log(
    "New connection",
    "Address: " + socket.address().address,
    "Port: " + socket.address().port
  );

  socket.setTimeout(55 * 1000);
  socket.on("timeout", () => {
    console.log("socket timeout");
    socket.end();
  });

  socket.on("close", hadError => {
    console.log(
      hadError
        ? "Socket closed due to ERROR during transmission"
        : "Socket closed"
    );
  });
});
```

The client receives the response "Thanks!" only once. Here are some images:

Client console: (in pink:client, in black: server)

[image]

This is the server console:

[image]

************* **EDIT** *************

Found workaround but still don't understand why it works only this way:

```
var response;
app.post("/enddev", (req, res) => {
  console.log("REQUEST TO ", req.route.path);
  console.log("Req Header ", req.headers);
  console.log("Body:", req.body);
  if (typeof response === "undefined") {
    response = res;
  }
  response.write("Hi Riko");
});
```

It seems that the new responses passed as argument `res` are not valid or something like that.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not ending the response at any point, e.g. through res.send() or res.end()?  That may be the problem, but I've not tested it.

Comment: Actually yes. The client is an embedded device with limited resources. res.send sends header alongside the data. I don't want it parsed on the end device. Moreover res.send closes the connection. It means every data exchange includes expensive TCP handshake procedure. There are more reasons but I do not want to focus on this. In my case  I need "keep-alive" connection.

Comment: Right, but if you never close the connection, you can't expect the HTTP protocol to work correctly.  It sounds like you should be using a different communications protocol.

Comment: Heroku doesn't support different protocol. The connection will close if no there is no data transfer for 55 seconds on the same connection